# Error: The method 'replacRange' isn't defined for the class 'List<int>'. - 'List' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: flutter, dart

i can't find this method.When i used this method i get the error like this:- Error: The method 'replacRange' isn't defined for the class 'List'.

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.[This is the code that i was done and get the error massage like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfyvh.png) in addition i can put the code in this Question also.
  Please give me the Solution...

```
void main(){
     var up1 = new List<int>.filled(0, 0, growable: true);
       up1.add(1);
       up1.add(2);
    

             up1.replacRange([44,22]);
}
```

Please give me the Solution...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achive with this code? Then I might be able to help you more specifically.

Other than that, the method you are trying to use is spelled **up1.replaceRange(...)**. This is the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.4/dart-core/List/replaceRange.html) for the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is '.replaceRange(...)' doesn't work like that!
you have to provide 3 paremeter!

1. starting index of where it should be replaced with. (included)
2. till which index it should replace. (excluded)
3. the replacing List.

Like:

```
  List<int> test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
 test.replaceRange(0, 2, [44, 22]);
print(test);
```

--> output: [44, 22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: It would be nice of you if I also get a thumps up :)